# How to call and pass values to a controller method from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, getjson

I have a http controller which is called from a getJSON method. Its working pretty good. But now I want to do the same operation performed in handler in a controller method. I am sending a value through getJSON to handler and it perform with that value.

Here is my getJSON

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('ProfileHandler.ashx', { 'ProfileName': 'Profile 1' }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            alert(v.Attribute+' : '+v.Value);               
        });            
    });
});
```

and here is my handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {                
            string strURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower();
            //string ProfileName = context.Request.QueryString["profilename"];
            string strProfileName = context.Request["ProfileName"];

            GetProfileDataService GetProfileDataService = new BokingEngine.MasterDataService.GetProfileDataService();
            IEnumerable<ProfileData> ProfileDetails = GetProfileDataService.GetList(new ProfileSearchCriteria { Name = strProfileName });
            JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string strSerProfileDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(ProfileDetails);
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
            context.Response.Write(strSerProfileDetails);
        }
        catch
        {
        }                        
    }
```

how can I call and pass 'ProfileName' to a controller method ?

Comment: You don't `POST` data with `GET`, but anyway those arguments usually are in request object

Comment: Yes, request only. Its working fine. My question is not about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct and you should be able to retrieve the ProfileName with the following:

```
string strProfileName = context.Request["ProfileName"];
```

And if you wanted to pass it to a controller action simply define this action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string profileName)
{
    var profileDataService = new BokingEngine.MasterDataService.GetProfileDataService();
    var request = new ProfileSearchCriteria { Name = profileName };
    var profileDetails = profileDataService.GetList(request);
    return Json(profileDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then invoke your controller action with AJAX:

```
<scirpt type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("SomeAction")';
        $.getJSON(url, { profileName: 'Profile 1' }, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                alert(v.Attribute + ' : ' + v.Value);
            });            
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: controller action not get invoked from ajax call

Comment: Did you verify if the `url` parameter is correct? In this example I have used the `@Url.Action("SomeAction")` server side helper to generate it, but in your case, are you using Razor and is this script inside your view or in a separate file? Make sure that the url you are passing to the `$.getJSON` method is correct. Also look in FireBug to see exactly to which address is the AJAX request being sent the reason for it failing.

Comment: I have created a controller with name 'ProfileDetails' and action 'GetProfile'. I want to call this action from separate aspx page through getJSON.

Comment: Alright, then make sure you have properly set the url to this controller action (the first parameter you are passing to the `$.getJSON` method). Here's how you could do that in your ASPX page: `var url = '<%= new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("GetProfile", "ProfileDetails") %>';`

Comment: Of course that it won't work in an ASPX WebForm! That's Razor syntax. Please use the proper syntax for your view engine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26020/discussion-between-sandy-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it.  Here is an example:

**Javascript**

```
function someFunction(e) {
    $.post("@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")", { ParameterName: e.value }, function(data) {
       $("#someDiv").html = data;
    });
}
```

**C# Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MethodName(string ParameterName)
{
    return "Hello " + ParameterName;
}
```

If you passed in your name to the JavaScript function "someFunction", the controller would return "Hello [your name]".  Help?